# How to activate loudspeaker in ios7 from our app?

Tags: ios

I want to turn on the speakerphone whenever my app is used also need to activate the speaker phone when the call is triggered from my app.

is it possible?

if so then please advice how to do?

Comment: Short Answer is `NO`.

Comment: Not even possible to activate speaker phone when my app is used? I tried as mentioned in below url but it doesn't helped [link](http://uihacker.blogspot.in/2013/08/ios-force-audio-output-to-speakers.html)

Answer (score 0):

This goes against Apple's sandbox limits. Apps only have a very limited number of resources that it may use. The speaker phone is a definite no. This would actually irritate users of your app. Consider a different approach to your current goal, would be the better route to take here.

For reference: **https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html**

Under the heading "The App Sandbox"

Comment: do you have any reference?